# Is it a good practice to use wait/notify in Android Java?

Tags: java, android

Is it considered a good practice to use Java threads wait/notify mechanism in Android?

I'm using it in a thread/AsyncTask which waits for events from another continuous thread.

EDIT: Android does not really use JVM, and its Java not the same as in PC. So the question is also about the Android's support and how it affects mobile specific sleep/UI Thread/ETC systems.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Do you need wait/notify methods for some particular task?

Comment: I need some sort of mechanism for a thread to wait for events. I found wait/notify is easy and solves my problem. The question is if using it considered good in Android, and I should not search a different solution which is more common/correct in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use wait() on the main thread then your UI Thread will freeze till some other method calls notify() and the execution of the further code starts.